# Recall, onCreateOptionsMenu method (more times)

Tags: android

I have this problem: in my `class.java` I have a private method (I call this in `onRemoteCallListenerComplete`) that elaborate a data that I want to appear in Menu. This method is not very fast and the application call the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method before `onRemoteCallListenerComplete` is finished.

I have read the use void `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method - to invalidate and re-call `onCreateOptionsMenu` - and I append this before `onRemoteCallListenerComplete` ended. However, `onOptionsItemSelected` method is not re-called.

NB: I'm sorry for my (terrible) English

The following i put my code

onCreateOptionsMenu method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dati_carriera, menu);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.expandableListView1_checkable);

    if(sizeValueCollection>0){
        item.setVisible(false);
    }else{
        boolean value = prefs.getBoolean(PREFERENCE_EXPANDIBLE_LIST_VIEW, true);    
        if(value)
            item.setChecked(true);
        else
            item.setChecked(false);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

onOptionsItemSelected method

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    Toast.makeText(this, "onOptionItemSelceted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    final ExpandableListView tv;
    int id=item.getItemId();
    switch(id){
    case R.id.expandableListView1_checkable:
        tv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        if(item.isChecked()){
            item.setChecked(false);
            tv.setVisibility(ExpandableListView.GONE);
            Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putBoolean(PREFERENCE_EXPANDIBLE_LIST_VIEW, false);
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }else{
            item.setChecked(true);
            tv.setVisibility(ExpandableListView.VISIBLE);
            Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putBoolean(PREFERENCE_EXPANDIBLE_LIST_VIEW, true);
            prefsEditor.commit();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

onRemoteCallListenerComplete

```
    @Override
public void onRemoteCallListenerComplete(String dati) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    [...]

    sizeValueCollection=valueCollection.size();
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

sizeValueCollection is a private int variable initialized to -1

Comment: `invalidateOptionsMenu` will re-call -> `onCreateOptionsMenu`, so the menu can be re-created. NOT `onOptionsItemSelected`. The method `onOptionsItemSelected` is only called when the user clicks on the menu item.

Answer (score 1):

try supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() if you use activity from support package

Comment: I extends Activity and this method is not usable. Eclipse indicate me the use invalidateOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to Menu object and update it after you receive all required data.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Menu menu;
    private MyMenuData myMenuData;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
       // Prepare menu
       this.menu = menu;
       if(myMenuData != null){
          // Data is loaded, menu can be updated now
          updateMenu(myMenuData);
       }
       return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void onRemoteCallListenerComplete(MyMenuData data){
       this.myMenuData = data;
       updateMenu(data);
    }

    private void updateMenu(MyMenuData menuData){
       // Update your menu here
    }
}
```

Comment: The result is equals to invalidateOptionsMenu (graphically speaking). The menu don't appears when i run application @andrey

Comment: Then you do something wrong. Create menu manually with some placeholders (without fetching data and using callbacks) and check if you do it correctly. Or update your question with code snippet

Comment: I have update the my original code. Look now @andrey

Comment: you call item.setVisible(false); and never true